# xcode 6 import enterprise provisioning profile

Tags: xcode, xcode6, provisioning-profile

I have received new mobileproviion file and certificate from my company i.e. the enterprise distribution profile. Could you please let me know How to import the mobileprovision profile into xcode 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply double-click each file. Although order doesn't really matter, I do the certificate first, then the mobileprovision file.  After, quit and relaunch Xcode.